# HIPAA Status? CloudSQL / Compute Engine VM

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

From my understanding, this is a feature that at some point will be implemented. To store PHI, you must now have a BAA. The BAA with Google Apps allows a person to utilize user accounts but limits PHI to email, calendar, and drive.

GAE can be secured by locking its user access to a Google Apps account, if that Google Apps account has the BAA, that's a great start.

Google VM's can be locked down to networks and protocols, which adds quite a bit of security on that end. Would be great to setup an SFTP to exchange PHI on a VM. If CloudSQL wasn't an option, a person could run MySQL from the VM.

CloudSQL PHI data could be encrypted before storing to the database.

It really seems like a very secure platform and easy to setup and maintain, but without the BAA for GAE, it doesn't do much good. Is there anyone at Google a person could contact about the possibility of signing a BAA as long as they followed safe practices? Something for early adopters. If not, what does the current timeline look like?

I know AWS is currently an option, but the capability of connecting Google App user accounts directly to GAE is such a great feature that I would much rather use GAE.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this announcement from February](http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.com/2014/02/google-cloud-platform-provides-support-for-hipaa-covered-entities.html), Google offers a BAA for the Cloud Platform. (which includes Cloud SQL and Compute Engine)  Since this is a legal agreement, it looks like you need to [contact the Google sales team](https://cloud.google.com/contact/) for more details.